# More efficient algorithm for shortest superstring search

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

My problem below is NP-complete, however, I'm trying to find at least a marginally faster string search function or module that might help in reducing some of the computation time compared to where it is at now. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The concatenated (longest possible) superstring is:

AGGAGTCCGCGTGAGGGAGGTGTAGTGTAGTGG

The below code produces the shortest superstring in 16m:

CCGTAGGTGGAGT

```
import itertools as it

def main():
    seqs = ['AGG', 'AGT', 'CCG', 'CGT', 'GAG', 'GGA', 'GGT', 'GTA', 'GTG', 'TAG', 'TGG']
    seq_perms = [''.join(perm) for perm in it.permutations(seqs)]
    for i in range(0, len(''.join(seqs))):
        seq_perms = [''.join(perm)[:i] for perm in it.permutations(seqs)]   
        for perm in seq_perms:   
            if all(perm.find(seq) != -1 for seq in seqs) == True:
                print 'Shortest superstring containing all strings:\n{}'.format(perm)
                return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any refactoring that completes in less time on my system will be marked solved.

Comment: That `return` seems very out of place, can you please provide example input (if there is any), and the expected output.

Comment: The return provides for the function to quit once the first superstring is generated, which in this case is the shortest. All possible superstrings are generated, then slices are taken of each possible superstring, with each being searched to find if they contain each string - growing larger with each iteration. The input is the 'seqs' list object, the output is as above, 'CCGTAGGTGGAGT'.

Comment: Please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20072009/1561176), I updated the code, now it only takes 5 minutes (On my machine).

Comment: A new update, thanks to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071702/more-efficient-algorithm-for-shortest-superstring-search/20072009?noredirect=1#comment29900736_20072009) - now it only takes ~2 minutes!

Comment: @InbarRose Much better than the original 29 m before restructuring :). If no other quicker answers post, I'll mark as correct.

Comment: @Alfe answered this little more than an hour after your last response but you didn't come back to it? Wow, okay. The best, fastest, and most clever should be given some credit, especially being 19x and 29x faster respectively.

Comment: @jacktrader Thank you for your outrage on my behalf, I appreciate this :-)  But the Q reads "Any refactoring that completes in less time on my system will be marked solved."  OP just kept their promise, accepted the first A which met the criteria and seemed to have left SO since then.  Moving the acceptance now would not be fair to Inbar Rose.  And since I got 40 upvotes for this answer I'd say I'm well served.

Comment: @Alfe Very good point, I automatically jumped to thinking in the traditional sense of the "best" solution and not what was phrased as "any". I'm not outraged but, just to throw it out there, technically as they were both submitted within an hour of eachother, I believe "both" answers would therefore be the accepted solution or share credit, but seeing that's not the way it works, it is what it is. To further illustrate my point, user2277435 also states "If no other quicker answers post, I'll mark as correct" which again would change the accepted solution, if so implicit or implied. Best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just backtracking, but always check most overlapped first. After get a good candidate answer, later when current path result in a string has length big or equal to this candidate answer, we do not need to go further with this path.

Tested in my Jupyter notebook. It seems to be much faster than the other two answers here (11/18/2018)

```
def shortestSuperstring(A):
    """
    :type A: List[str]
    :rtype: str
    """

    if len(A)==1:
        return A[0]
    dic={}
    for i in xrange(len(A)):
        for j in xrange(len(A)):
            if i!=j:
                ol=0
                for k in xrange(1,min(len(A[i]),len(A[j]))):
                    if A[j][:k]==A[i][-k:]:
                        ol=k
                dic[(i,j)]=ol
    if max(dic.values())==0:
        return "".join(A)
    else:
        ret="".join(A)
        l=len(ret)
        stack=[]
        for i,wd in enumerate(A):
            tmp=set(range(len(A)))
            tmp.remove(i)
            stack.append((wd,i,tmp))
        while stack:
            ans,cur,remain=stack.pop()
            if len(ans)<l:
                if not remain:
                    ret=ans
                    l=len(ret)
                else:
                    tmp=[[dic[cur,idx],idx] for idx in remain] # [#overlap,idx]
                    tmp.sort()
                    for ol,idx in tmp:
                        nans=ans+A[idx][ol:]
                        nremain=set(remain)
                        nremain.remove(idx)
                        stack.append((nans,idx,nremain))
        return ret
```

The test case in the problem takesL

```
1.93 s ± 160 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

to run and gives the answer:

```
'CCGTGGTAGGAGT'
```

Some other test cases (longer strings and that start to beat the other two methods, all about 1~5 seconds):

```
    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['mftpvodataplkewcouz', 'krrgsoxpsnmzlhprsl', 'qhbfymytxzbmqma', 'hunjgeaolcuznhpodi', 'kewcouzbwlftz', 'xzbmqmahunjgeaolcu', 'zlhprslqurnqbhsjr', 'rrgsoxpsnmzlhprslqur', 'diqukrrgsoxpsnmz', 'sjrxzavamftpvoda']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  qhbfymytxzbmqmahunjgeaolcuznhpodiqukrrgsoxpsnmzlhprslqurnqbhsjrxzavamftpvodataplkewcouzbwlftz


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['cedefifgstkyxfcuajfa', 'ooncedefifgstkyxfcua', 'assqjfwarvjcjedqtoz', 'fcuajfassqjfwarvjc', 'fwarvjcjedqtozctcd', 'zppedxfumcfsngp', 'kyxfcuajfassqjfwa', 'fumcfsngphjyfhhwkqa', 'fassqjfwarvjcjedq', 'ppedxfumcfsngphjyf', 'dqtozctcdk']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  zppedxfumcfsngphjyfhhwkqaooncedefifgstkyxfcuajfassqjfwarvjcjedqtozctcdk


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['ekpijtseahvmprvefkgn', 'yyevvcmeekpijtseahvm', 'vsfcyyevvcmeekp', 'xwmkoqhxvrovlmmvsfcy', 'cmeekpijtseahvmpr', 'oqhxvrovlmmvsfcyy', 'zpuemtclxbxwsypfxevx', 'clxbxwsypfxevxw', 'fkgnjgdvfygnlckyiju', 'xevxwmkoqhxvrovlmm']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  zpuemtclxbxwsypfxevxwmkoqhxvrovlmmvsfcyyevvcmeekpijtseahvmprvefkgnjgdvfygnlckyiju


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['ppgortnmsy', 'czmysoeeyugbiylso', 'nbfzpppvhbjydtx', 'rnzynedhoiunkpon', 'ornzynedhoiunkpo', 'ylsomoktkyfgljcf', 'jtvkrornzynedhoiunk', 'hvhhihwdffmxnczmyso', 'ktkyfgljcfbkqcpp', 'nzynedhoiunkponbfz', 'nedhoiunkponbfzpppvh']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  hvhhihwdffmxnczmysoeeyugbiylsomoktkyfgljcfbkqcppgortnmsyjtvkrornzynedhoiunkponbfzpppvhbjydtx


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['amefulhsdgvjvoab', 'giqxpqszaitzfzvtalx', 'cyqeolfgkihssycmiodg', 'glhhcfuprwazet', 'cmiodgiqxpqszaitzf', 'lhsdgvjvoabdviglhhcf', 'ssycmiodgiqxpqsza', 'bxtdqnamefulhsdg', 'namefulhsdgvjvo', 'ihssycmiodgiqxp', 'itzfzvtalxfybxtdqn']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  cyqeolfgkihssycmiodgiqxpqszaitzfzvtalxfybxtdqnamefulhsdgvjvoabdviglhhcfuprwazet


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['yobbobwqymlordokxka', 'jllfoebgbsrguls', 'rgulsnatnpuuwiyba', 'ordokxkamymamofefr', 'wqymlordokxkamy', 'fycxifzsjllfoebgbsrg', 'lordokxkamymamofe', 'kxkamymamofefrmfycx', 'frmfycxifzsjllf', 'srgulsnatnpuuwiy']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  yobbobwqymlordokxkamymamofefrmfycxifzsjllfoebgbsrgulsnatnpuuwiyba


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['jnbbbbsczcscxawcze', 'bsczcscxawczeumyyr', 'lyofvbhvjmquhkgz', 'quhkgzyzdwtjnbbb', 'kgzyzdwtjnbbbbsczc', 'uouxnfplptpkgnronf', 'pqgyfqglyofvbhv', 'kgnronftgswvpqgy', 'marvhdxtbmkcpnli', 'qgyfqglyofvbhvjmquhk', 'xtbmkcpnliz']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  marvhdxtbmkcpnlizuouxnfplptpkgnronftgswvpqgyfqglyofvbhvjmquhkgzyzdwtjnbbbbsczcscxawczeumyyr


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['qrwpawefqzfjsan', 'jsanzdukfkdlmyox', 'neaxnkedjxbpgsyq', 'nqjvzryhfjdsxmwolwo', 'hfjdsxmwolwomeeewvi', 'lmyoxbpvkneaxnkedjxb', 'qbhpqrwpawefqzfjsa', 'pawefqzfjsanzdukfk', 'bqbhpqrwpawefqzfj', 'dlmyoxbpvkneaxnk', 'xnkedjxbpgsyqovvh']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  bqbhpqrwpawefqzfjsanzdukfkdlmyoxbpvkneaxnkedjxbpgsyqovvhnqjvzryhfjdsxmwolwomeeewvi


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['vgrikrnwezryimj', 'umwgwvzpsfpmctzt', 'pjourlpgeemdjor', 'urlpgeemdjorpzbkbz', 'jorpzbkbzcqyewih', 'xuwkzvoczozhhvf', 'ihbumoogibirbsvch', 'nwezryimjivvpjourlp', 'kzvoczozhhvfwgeplv', 'ezryimjivvpjourlpgee', 'zhhvfwgeplvqngglu', 'rikrnwezryimjivvp']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  xuwkzvoczozhhvfwgeplvqngglumwgwvzpsfpmctztvgrikrnwezryimjivvpjourlpgeemdjorpzbkbzcqyewihbumoogibirbsvch


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['nbsgonqmpreelpbr', 'hnysjajtiguehrokus', 'udgzbzmevnkzzba', 'axtbmcpbmoubyoscn', 'vqnbsgonqmpreel', 'xvqnbsgonqmpree', 'ajtiguehrokustktudgz', 'brgkgihuetpqrhhbhn', 'dgzbzmevnkzzbaxtbmcp', 'ehrokustktudgzbzmevn', 'uetpqrhhbhnysjaj', 'vnkzzbaxtbmcpbmo']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  xvqnbsgonqmpreelpbrgkgihuetpqrhhbhnysjajtiguehrokustktudgzbzmevnkzzbaxtbmcpbmoubyoscn


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['orugbsuuxowmhjh', 'zjyxzmpduthlsioor', 'qtxocgehmhfqnstl', 'tlrlcnnrsyryfrywuebq', 'hozjyxzmpduthlsio', 'hjhdmnqtxocgehm', 'mjhzwdudlnbfkjawqacf', 'hfqnstlrlcnnrsyryfry', 'yfrywuebqhvwewzmq', 'zzieemjhzwdudlnbfkj', 'nnrsyryfrywuebqhvw', 'acfgaihbhozjyxzmpdut']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  zzieemjhzwdudlnbfkjawqacfgaihbhozjyxzmpduthlsioorugbsuuxowmhjhdmnqtxocgehmhfqnstlrlcnnrsyryfrywuebqhvwewzmq


    ****************************************************************************************************


    case: 

     ['phuutlgczfspygaljkv', 'fspygaljkvahvuii', 'csywjodtnkynkjckq', 'poyykqyrhbvcwvjl', 'xijupvzzwphuutlg', 'aljkvahvuiivqbqrw', 'vahvuiivqbqrwryd', 'wjodtnkynkjckqurgu', 'ecdmbshotqbxjqgbou', 'hvuiivqbqrwrydgnr', 'ivqbqrwrydgnrubcsywj', 'wphuutlgczfspyga']


    ****************************************************************************************************


    ans:  ecdmbshotqbxjqgbouxijupvzzwphuutlgczfspygaljkvahvuiivqbqrwrydgnrubcsywjodtnkynkjckqurgupoyykqyrhbvcwvjl
```

Also see the dynamic programming approach:
https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-shortest-superstring/solution/

Answer (score 49):

I applied the Dijkstra algorithm (width-search) and have a solution giving an answer to this task in less than a second.  I optimized it a bit in terms of memory usage, but I think concerning the algorithm this is a better approach than the one in the other answer.  Unless we run out of memory this should be a better solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dijkSuperstring(originalSeqs):
  paths = defaultdict(set)
  paths[0] =  { '' }
  while paths:
    minLength = min(paths.keys())
    while paths[minLength]:
      candidate = paths[minLength].pop()
      seqAdded = False
      for seq in originalSeqs:
        if seq in candidate:
          continue
        seqAdded = True
        for i in reversed(range(len(seq)+1)):
          if candidate.endswith(seq[:i]):
            newCandidate = candidate + seq[i:]
            paths[len(newCandidate)].add(newCandidate)
      if not seqAdded:  # nothing added, so all present?
        return candidate
    del paths[minLength]

print dijkSuperstring(
  [ 'AGG', 'AGT', 'CCG', 'CGT', 'GAG', 'GGA', 'GGT', 'GTA', 'GTG', 'TAG', 'TGG' ])
```

I also tried using random sequences as input:

```
seqs = [ ''.join(random.choice('GATC')
  for i in range(3))
    for j in range(11) ]
print dijkSuperstring(deqs)
```

I soon found out that the solving time greatly depends on the size of the result(!) not of the input's size (so it isn't predictable).  This isn't too surprising, but it makes comparing different algorithms a little difficult as others don't necessarily also have this property.  In particular, the set of sequences from the OP seems to pose a comparatively lightweight problem.  Other sets of 11 sequences of 3 characters are much harder to solve.

So I made some statistical measurements; I solved 1000 sets of 8 sequences.  This I did for sequences of 3 and of 4 characters.  Then I grouped the durations in 100 groups (equally spaced from 0s to the highest duration) and counted how many fell into each group.  To smoothen the graph I always used the sum of three neighboring groups.

The diagrams below each show two such experiments, performed with an earlier (non-optimized) version of my algorithm (but the shape of the curves are the same as now); I did it twice to at least have an idea whether a strange ditch in the graph could have a reason or was just by pure chance.

I'd be interested to see similar graphs for the same kind of input for other algorithms.  This could be interesting because my algorithm clearly has a memory issue.  Solving 11 sequences of 3 characters stalled my machine several times due to memory exhaustion, so having another algorithm could make sense even if it is slower.

## 8 Sequences of 3 Characters

[image: 8 Sequences of 3 Characters]

## 8 Sequences of 4 Characters

[image: 8 Sequences of 4 Characters]

Comment: Why not more upvotes for this solution? It sounds like it's much faster and also gets the correct answer. Did someone try running both and comparing the timing?

Comment: I guess I just was a little late, and now nobody's interested anymore ;-) I can live with that.

Comment: I tried both Alfe's version and Inbar's. They both find the same solution, in 1s and 29s respectively. Alfe, I tip my hat to you.

Comment: Very clever and fast!

Comment: This never produced the intended result, and no, as such, does not get awarded the correct answer. Fastest solution, not fastest output.

Comment: @user2277435  Why do you think the answers it produces aren't correct?  To my observations, they are.

Answer (score 8):

This should do it.

```
import itertools as it

SEQUENCES = ['AGG', 'AGT', 'CCG', 'CGT', 'GAG', 'GGA', 'GGT', 'GTA', 'GTG', 'TAG', 'TGG']
LONGEST_SUPERSTRING = ''.join(SEQUENCES)

def find_shortest_superstring():
    current_shortest = LONGEST_SUPERSTRING
    trim = len(current_shortest)-1
    seen_prefixes = set()
    for perm in it.permutations(SEQUENCES):
        candidate_string = ''.join(perm)[:trim]
        if candidate_string in seen_prefixes:
            continue
        seen_prefixes.add(candidate_string)
        while is_superstring(candidate_string):
            current_shortest = candidate_string
            candidate_string = candidate_string[:-1]
            trim = len(current_shortest)-1
    return current_shortest

def is_superstring(s):
    return all(seq in s for seq in SEQUENCES)

def main():
    print 'Searching for shortest superstring containing all strings.'
    ss = find_shortest_superstring()
    print 'Found shortest superstring containing all strings:\n{}'.format(ss)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

The code takes about 15 seconds to run and produces the following output:

```
Searching for shortest superstring containing all strings.
Found shortest superstring containing all strings:
CCGTAGGTGGAGT
```

Comment: Couldn't you truncate `candidate_string` to `len(current_shortest)-1` before the loop, and then simply `while is_superstring(...`?

Comment: @JanneKarila Good point, I switched `candidate_string = ''.join(perm)` to `candidate_string = ''.join(perm)[:len(current_shortest)]` Now it only takes ~2 minutes! :)

Comment: I also meant you could eliminate the if/elif/else by changing to `while is_superstring(...`. You need to truncate one more character for that to work.

Comment: Yeah, if you change `candidate_string = ''.join(perm)[:len(current_shortest)]` so that it does `...[:len(current_shortest)-1]` then checking the length within the loop is unneded, so you could have just `while is_superstring(candidate_string): current_shortest = candidate_string; candidate_string = candidate_string[:-1]`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to compute `len(current_shortest)` for every permutation but only when you actually detect a new `current_shortest` value, so I suggest to introduce a new `current_shortest_len` variable to keep track of that.

Comment: In Python the `len()` function does not compute anything, the length is already stored. I will look into your other suggestion.

Comment: @Inbar Rose: `python -m cProfile superscript.py` seems to disagree: `len` does cause calls (39916800 calls, in fact) which eat 2.8 seconds for me.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I am pretty sure it would cost more time to assign and read values for a new variable called len_shortest which I would have to initiate before the permutations loop, and set each time a new item is the shortest...

Comment: @Inbar Rose: Well try to profile it. `len` accesses a variable as well (the function `len` itself as well as the argument), and you only actually update the `current_shortest_len` variable exactly 21 times, because that's how many shorter strings you find.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Okay - Instead of just storing the len, I just precalculate the trim amount. Saves more than 2.8 seconds. :)

Comment: A very good optimization might also be to skip all those permutations which have the same prefix, i.e. have a set `seen_prefixes` and then do `if candidate_string in seen_prefixes: continue; seen_prefixes.add(candidate_string)` at the top of your loop. Brings the runtime from ~50 seconds down to ~27 for me.