# Punch/Combine multiple strings into a single (shortest possible) string that includes all the chars of each strings in forward direction

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

My purpose is to punch multiple strings into a single (shortest) string that will contain all the character of each string in a forward direction. The question is not specific to any language, but more into the `algorithm` part. (probably will implement it in a node server, so tagging `nodejs/javascript`).

So, to explain the problem:

Let's consider I have few strings

```
["jack", "apple", "maven", "hold", "solid", "mark", "moon", "poor", "spark", "live"]
```

The Resultant string should be something like:

```
"sjmachppoalidveonrk"
```

jack: s**j**m**ac**hppoalidveonr**k**

apple: sjm**a**ch**pp**oa**l**idv**e**onrk

solid: **s**jmachpp**o**a**lid**veonrk

====================================>>>> all in the forward direction

These all are manual evaluation and the output may not 100% perfect in the example.

So, the point is all the letters of each string have to exist in  the output in 
**FORWARD DIRECTION** (here the actual problem belongs), and possibly the server will send the final strings and numbers like `27594` will be generated and passed to extract the token, in the required end. If I have to punch it in a minimal possible string it would have much easier (That case only unique chars are enough). But in this case there are some points:

1. Letters can be present multiple time, though I have to reuse any
   letter if possible, eg: for `solid` and `hold` `o > l > d` can be
   reused as forward direction but for `apple` (`a > p`) and `spark`
   (`p > a`) we have to repeat `a` as in one case it appears before `p`
   for `apple`, and after `p` for `sparks` so either we need to repeat
   `a` or `p`. Even, we cannot do `p > a > p` as it will not cover both the case
   because we need two `p` after `a` for `apple`
2. We directly have no option to place a single `p` and use the same
   index twice in a time of extract, we need multiple `p` with no option
   left as the input string contains that
3. I am (not) sure, that there is multiple outputs possible for a set of
   strings. but the concern is it should be minimal in length,
   the combination doesn't matter if its cover all the tokens in a forward direction. all (or one ) outputs of minimal possible length 
   need to trace.
4. Adding this point as an **EDIT** to this post. After reading the comments and knowing that it's already an existing
   problem is known as  [shortest common supersequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem) we can
   define that the resultant string will be the shortest possible
   string from which we can re generate any input string by simply
   removing some (0 to N) chars, this is same as all inputs can be found in a forward direction in the resultant string.

I have tried, by starting with an arbitrary string, and then made an analysis of next string and splitting all the letters, and place them accordingly, but after some times, it seems that current string letters can be placed in a better way, If the last string's (or a previous string's) letters were placed according to the current string. But again that string was analysed and placed based on something (multiple) what was processed, and placing something in the favor of something that is not processed seems difficult because to that we need to process that. Or might me maintaining a tree of all processed/unprocessed tree will help, building the building the final string? Any better way than it, it seems a brute force?

**Note**: I know there are a lot of other transformation possible, please try not to suggest anything else to use, we are doing a bit research on it.

Comment: @Downvoters, you can explain the reason in comment, as it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: I havent voted, but this reads like a CS homework problem, could be the reason for the negative attention.

Comment: @viraj_os Well, not at all, atleast that can be clarified if someone think so, or atleast shouldn't discouraged if can't have a solution. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: This problem is known as the [shortest common supersequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem).

Comment: @mhum thanx for the info. Exactly the same case here, for 2 string easily we can find, but with more than 2 it's hard to find a solution (best case)

Comment: Is it fine if I answer for this problem in java?

Comment: @CodeHunter well absolutely, the focus is the `algorithm` here.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee: I came up with a solution based on DP. But it is costly in terms of number of strings. The final complexity is coming to be `O(n1*n2....*nx)` but the resultant string will definitely be the shortest possible one. I just want to confirm if you have tried it using DP before?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee: Not sure if it helps, but for `n>2`, this problem is `NP-Complete`.

Comment: @CodeHunter thanks for your response, will check your answer and revert on the answer..

Comment: [Dijkstra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20074602/3789665)

Comment: `multiple outputs possible for a set of strings`: consider sets with at least one pair of characters that occur at the same end of strings, only.

Comment: @greybeard yeah, I knew that, so the min length of any combination would be file, my focus is min length. even in the example you can start with different chars I guess

Answer (score 7):

I came up with a somewhat brute force method. This way finds the optimal way to combine 2 words then does it for each element in the array.

This strategy works by trying finding the best possible way to combine 2 words together. It is considered the best by having the fewest letters. Each word is fed into an ever growing "merged" word. Each time a new word is added the existing word is searched for a matching character which exists in the word to be merged. Once one is found both are split into 2 sets and attempted to be joined (using the rules at hand, no need 2 add if letter already exists ect..). The strategy generally yields good results.

The `join_word` method takes 2 words you wish to join, the first parameter is considered to be the word you wish to place the other into. It then searches for the best way to split `into` and `word` into 2 separate parts to merge together, it does this by looking for any shared common characters. This is where the `splits_on_letter` method comes in.

The `splits_on_letter` method takes a word and a letter which you wish to split on, then returns a 2d array of all the possible left and right sides of splitting on that character. For example `splits_on_letter('boom', 'o')` would return `[["b","oom"],["bo","om"],["boo","m"]]`, this is all the combinations of how we could use the letter `o` as a split point.

---

The `sort()` at the beginning is to attempt to place like elements together. The order in which you merge the elements generally effects the results length. One approach I tried was to sort them based upon how many common letters they used (with their peers), however the results were varying. However in all my tests I had maybe 5 or 6 different word sets to test with, its possible with a larger, more varying word arrays you might find different results.

Output is

```
spmjhooarckpplivden
```

```js
var words = ["jack", "apple", "maven", "hold", "solid", "mark", "moon", "poor", "spark", "live"];
var result = minify_words(words);
document.write(result);

function minify_words(words) {
    // Theres a good sorting method somewhere which can place this in an optimal order for combining them,
    // hoever after quite a few attempts i couldnt get better than just a regular sort... so just use that
    words = words.sort();

    /*
        Joins 2 words together ensuring each word has all its letters in the result left to right
    */
    function join_word(into, word) {
        var best = null;
        // straight brute force each word down. Try to run a split on each letter and 
        for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++) {
            var letter = word[i];
            // split our 2 words into 2 segments on that pivot letter
            var intoPartsArr = splits_on_letter(into, letter);
            var wordPartsArr = splits_on_letter(word, letter);
            for(var p1=0;p1<intoPartsArr.length;p1++) {
                for(var p2=0;p2<wordPartsArr.length;p2++) {
                    var intoParts = intoPartsArr[p1], wordParts = wordPartsArr[p2];
                    // merge left and right and push them together
                    var result = add_letters(intoParts[0], wordParts[0]) + add_letters(intoParts[1], wordParts[1]);
                    if(!best || result.length <= best.length) {
                        best = result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // its possible that there is no best, just tack the words together at that point
        return best || (into + word);
    }

    /*
        Splits a word at the index of the provided letter
    */
    function splits_on_letter(word, letter) {
        var ix, result = [], offset = 0;;
        while((ix = word.indexOf(letter, offset)) !== -1) {
            result.push([word.substring(0, ix), word.substring(ix, word.length)]);
            offset = ix+1;
        }
        result.push([word.substring(0, offset), word.substring(offset, word.length)]);
        return result;
    }


    /*
        Adds letters to the word given our set of rules. Adds them starting left to right, will only add if the letter isnt found
    */
    function add_letters(word, addl) {
        var rIx = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < addl.length; i++) {
            var foundIndex = word.indexOf(addl[i], rIx);
            if (foundIndex == -1) {
                word = word.substring(0, rIx) + addl[i] + word.substring(rIx, word.length);
                rIx += addl[i].length;
            } else {
                rIx = foundIndex + addl[i].length;
            }
        }
        return word;
    }

    // For each of our words, merge them together
    var joinedWords = words[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        joinedWords = join_word(joinedWords, words[i]);
    }
    return joinedWords;
}
```

Comment: hmm, seems brute force. anyway, thanks for your effort and involvement. Can you explain the flow on a high level. anyway, is that sort is really needed??

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Updated my answer, no the sort is not needed, however it generally seems to reduce the size. Theres more detail in the updates i placed in as well. After looking and playing with the problem a bit more I think theres always going to be some sort of brute forcing going on *if your looking for optimal results*.

Comment: hmmm.. so, it seems when you are processing each word, you are trying to update the existing output (combined string string so far) before placing the chars (if required) of current string to the output in such a way so that we need minimal entry in the current output. which is good, and somehow I also feel (in my opinion from the beginning) that is the key to achieve the shortest result in optimal processing. Good. +1

Comment: For the given example the returned solution is optimal (for all characters find the word with max occurences and sum up... but there is at least one conflict spark/apple, the a comes once before and once after p, so the optimal solution has to be at least one character longer... which is exactly the number of character of the returned solution and therefore it has to be optimal).

Answer (score 3):

A first try, not really optimized (183% shorter):

```
function getShort(arr){
 var perfect="";
 //iterate the array
 arr.forEach(function(string){
   //iterate over the characters in the array
   string.split("").reduce(function(pos,char){    
     var n=perfect.indexOf(char,pos+1);//check if theres already a possible char
     if(n<0){      
       //if its not existing, simply add it behind the current

        perfect=perfect.substr(0,pos+1)+char+perfect.substr(pos+1);
       return pos+1;
     }
     return n;//continue with that char
    },-1);
  })
  return perfect;
}
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/gatoxanabi/edit?console)

---

This can be improved trough simply running the upper code with some variants of the array (200% improvement):

```
var s=["jack",...];
var perfect=null;
for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
 //shift
 s.push(s.shift());
 var result=getShort(s);
 if(!perfect || result.length<perfect.length) perfect=result;
}
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/mitoxahanu/edit?console)

Thats quite close to the minimum number of characters ive [estimated](http://jsbin.com/derajurijo/edit?console) ( 244% minimization might be possible in the best case)

Ive also wrote a function to get the minimal number of chars and one to check if a certain word fails, you can find them [here](http://jsbin.com/yeveqawawi/edit?console)

Comment: Part1: Thanks for your response, kinda same thing I have tried (processing each item and placed the chars of them in a output as I mentioned in the question), now in the optimization it will change the sequence for inout like `[S1, S2, S3]` to `[S2, S3, S1]` and `[S3, S1, S2]` and will take the best (shortest) of it

Comment: Part 2: I feel (as you also mentioned) if we can take the all combinations (eg include `[S1, S3, S2]` and `[S2, S1, S3]` and ....) then possible will get the shortest, that's a complete brute-force again. but for placing chars is almost good I will say. anyways thanks for your response and involvement towards solution of this. :)

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee im still working on a better approach... not yet found sth :/

Answer (score 3):

I have used the idea of **Dynamic programming** to first generate the shortest possible string in *forward direction* as stated in OP. Then I have combined the result obtained in the previous step to send as a parameter along with the next String in the list. Below is the working code in `java`. Hope this would help to reach the most optimal solution, in case my solution is identified to be non optimal. Please feel free to report any countercases for the below code:

```
public String shortestPossibleString(String a, String b){
    int[][] dp = new int[a.length()+1][b.length()+1];
            //form the dynamic table consisting of 
            //length of shortest substring till that points 
    for(int i=0;i<=a.length();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=b.length();j++){
            if(i == 0)
                dp[i][j] = j;
            else if(j == 0)
                dp[i][j] = i;
                            else if(a.charAt(i-1) == b.charAt(j-1))
                dp[i][j] = 1+dp[i-1][j-1];
            else
                dp[i][j] = 1+Math.min(dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1]);

        }
    }
            //Backtrack from here to find the shortest substring
            char[] sQ = new char[dp[a.length()][b.length()]];
            int s = dp[a.length()][b.length()]-1;
            int i=a.length(), j=b.length();
            while(i!=0 && j!=0){
                // If current character in a and b are same, then
                // current character is part of shortest supersequence
                if(a.charAt(i-1) == b.charAt(j-1)){
                    sQ[s] = a.charAt(i-1);
                    i--;
                    j--;
                    s--;
                }
                else {
                    // If current character in a and b are different
                    if(dp[i-1][j] > dp[i][j-1]){
                        sQ[s] = b.charAt(j-1);
                        j--;
                        s--;
                    }
                    else{
                        sQ[s] = a.charAt(i-1);
                        i--;
                        s--;
                    }
                }                        
            }
            // If b reaches its end, put remaining characters
            // of a in the result string
            while(i!=0){
                sQ[s] = a.charAt(i-1);
                i--;
                s--;
            }
            // If a reaches its end, put remaining characters
            // of b in the result string
            while(j!=0){
                sQ[s] = b.charAt(j-1);
                j--;
                s--;
            }
    return String.valueOf(sQ);
}
    public void getCombinedString(String... values){
        String sSQ = shortestPossibleString(values[0],values[1]);
        for(int i=2;i<values.length;i++){
            sSQ = shortestPossibleString(values[i],sSQ);
        }
        System.out.println(sSQ);
    }
```

Driver program:

```
e.getCombinedString("jack", "apple", "maven", "hold", 
            "solid", "mark", "moon", "poor", "spark", "live");
```

Output:

`jmapphsolivecparkonidr`

Worst case time complexity of the above solution would be `O(product of length of all input strings)` when all strings have all characters distinct and not even a single character matches between any pair of strings.

Comment: hjmsappoorcklivedn

Comment: @greybeard:  `hjmsappoorcklivedn ` would be incorrect. It does not form `spark` in forward direction. Please check.

Comment: Right - make that hjmsapapoorcklivend, then. (mistake in reformatting/reordering "jmhsa poopa rckli vedn"…)

Comment: @greybeard: will check that part and update. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: After digging up more, it seems that for `n>2` this problem is `NP-Complete`.

Comment: (That's why I didn't start "designing" an algorithm, let alone coding.)

Comment: Yeah, I am on the same place for the problem.. `N>2` is what I am looking for, not at all bothered up to 2 words.

Comment: Not sure you can always reduce all the possibilities down to 1 after each added string. Take ["ab", "ac", "bc"] for example. In your solution, you would get either "abc" or "acb" after the first one and it wouldn't have a preference. But "abc" gives you "abc" when combined with "bc" while "acb" gives you "acbc" or "abcb", not the optimal solution. You will get the opposite result if you switch the "ab" and "ac" in the array.

Comment: @csander: True. It will be really difficult to come up with a generalized efficient solution for a large number of strings. Something or the other would hinder that. Be it time complexity or the memory constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an optimal solution based on dynamic programming in JavaScript, but it can only get through `solid` on my computer before it runs out of memory. It differs from @CodeHunter's solution in that it keeps the entire set of optimal solutions after each added string, not just one of them. You can see that the number of optimal solutions grows exponentially; even after `solid` there are already 518,640 optimal solutions.

```
const STRINGS = ["jack", "apple", "maven", "hold", "solid", "mark", "moon", "poor", "spark", "live"]
function map(set, f) {
    const result = new Set
    for (const o of set) result.add(f(o))
    return result
}
function addAll(set, other) {
    for (const o of other) set.add(o)
    return set
}
function shortest(set) { //set is assumed non-empty
    let minLength
    let minMatching
    for (const s of set) {
        if (!minLength || s.length < minLength) {
            minLength = s.length
            minMatching = new Set([s])
        }
        else if (s.length === minLength) minMatching.add(s)
    }
    return minMatching
}
class ZipCache {
    constructor() {
        this.cache = new Map
    }
    get(str1, str2) {
        const cached1 = this.cache.get(str1)
        if (!cached1) return undefined
        return cached1.get(str2)
    }
    set(str1, str2, zipped) {
        let cached1 = this.cache.get(str1)
        if (!cached1) {
            cached1 = new Map
            this.cache.set(str1, cached1)
        }
        cached1.set(str2, zipped)
    }
}
const zipCache = new ZipCache
function zip(str1, str2) {
    const cached = zipCache.get(str1, str2)
    if (cached) return cached

    if (!str1) { //str1 is empty, so only choice is str2
        const result = new Set([str2])
        zipCache.set(str1, str2, result)
        return result
    }
    if (!str2) { //str2 is empty, so only choice is str1
        const result = new Set([str1])
        zipCache.set(str1, str2, result)
        return result
    }
    //Both strings start with same letter
    //so optimal solution must start with this letter
    if (str1[0] === str2[0]) {
        const zipped = zip(str1.substring(1), str2.substring(1))
        const result = map(zipped, s => str1[0] + s)
        zipCache.set(str1, str2, result)
        return result
    }

    //Either do str1[0] + zip(str1[1:], str2)
    //or        str2[0] + zip(str1, str2[1:])
    const zip1 = zip(str1.substring(1), str2)
    const zip2 = zip(str1, str2.substring(1))
    const test1 = map(zip1, s => str1[0] + s)
    const test2 = map(zip2, s => str2[0] + s)
    const result = shortest(addAll(test1, test2))
    zipCache.set(str1, str2, result)
    return result
}
let cumulative = new Set([''])
for (const string of STRINGS) {
    console.log(string)
    const newCumulative = new Set
    for (const test of cumulative) {
        addAll(newCumulative, zip(test, string))
    }
    cumulative = shortest(newCumulative)
    console.log(cumulative.size)
}
console.log(cumulative) //never reached
```